# Differences between large numbers with many factors has little factors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I apologise beforehand for the informality and lack of precision in this question but it is that way because it comes from only an intuition, nothing more than a heuristic argument.

Say one has two large, relatively coprime numbers relatively close to each other ( relative to their own size) so that both numbers have a large amount of prime factors( large relative to the usual amount for numbers of that size) in their factorisations. Then, their difference is relatively small and cannot be divisible by any prime within the factorisations of the two large numbers. Hence, it seems reasonable that this small number must have a small amount of prime factors(relative to the usual amount for numbers of that size), since there are several primes it cannot be divisible by.

Computing several such examples, I find that this is indeed mostly the case. Often, the difference of the two numbers is prime. What I am wondering is whether there are some rigorous ways to express this fact. I'm thinking maybe it would involve something about the distributions of the values of some function like the divisor function, the sum of divisors function, or the amount of prime factors function or something of the sort.

Any further loose thoughts and ideas that add to this are welcome. 
Thanks.

Comment: "it seems reasonable that this small number must have a small amount of prime factors...." It is trivial that *any* small number must have a small number of prime factors. You're going to have to put a lot more thought into this to make it a sensible question.

Comment: Gerry Myerson, a small number compared to the "normal" amount for numbers of that size ( since there are several prime factors it cannot be divisible by)

Comment: Please edit that into your question, together with similar clarifications for some of the other statements.

Comment: Ok, done. Thanks for the suggestion Gerry Myerson.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? What would be a pair of such numbers in the vicinity of, say, 8510984424780437317235870?

Comment: Factoring 8510984424780437317235870 into primes using mathematica gives: 2*5*11*17*23*31*41*47*59*67*73*83*97*103*109*127 it certainly has a lot of factors... the number 13×29×37x43×53×61³x79x89x101²×113×119 also has roughly as many factors and is roughly the same size and has no factors in common as the previous one (roughly each 8.5 and 7.0 times 10 to the power of 24).. if we work out their difference we get...

Comment: 1551738963691959676581663... which factoring again in wolfra alpha is equal to 3²*17²*10883*9519919*5758328419 ... still a lot of factors, but significantly less than the starting two... ( note it doesnt have any of the prime factors any of the starting two had)

Comment: so the heuristic holds

Comment: "note it doesnt have any of the prime factors any of the starting two had": well, obviously.

Comment: My intuition on this is that any attempt to turn your intuition on this into a rigorous statement is going to fail.

Comment: @Assaultous2 Notice that $5$ prime factors is pretty much average for numbers of this size.  The asymptotic average is $\ln \ln n$ which is pretty close to $4$, but that's ignoring some lower-order terms.  (A quick sample of 1000 random numbers shows an empirical average of $4.4$).  It would be a stretch to call this "small" relative to normal numbers of that size.

Comment: And measuring non-distinct prime factors (i.e. $\omega(n)$ versus $\Omega(n)$), the empirical average is 4.9, but the sample number has 7.

Comment: Point accepted. But small compared to the initial two numbers, no?

Comment: But that's only because the number itself is small compared to the initial two numbers.

Comment: To go back to Alonzo's example: notice anything special about the prime factors of 8510984424780437317235870? This gave me the idea of trying out 471681857112151855812279. Their difference is 8039302567668285461423591, which is obviously not divisible by any prime smaller than 131, and might even be prime itself. It is composite, it has only three prime factors, so... oh, wait, I see what you're saying.

Comment: @Assaultous2 I would go further than TonyK.  It's only small compared to the initial two numbers because the initial two numbers were chosen to be exceptionally rich in factors.  For it to _not_ be smaller would be an incredible coincidence.

Comment: @ Erick Wrong: Yes, of course they are "exceptionally rich in factors"... the question says: large numbers with many factors! That's the whole point.

Comment: @Assaultous2 To summarize: the whole point of your question is that certain small numbers have "few" prime factors, but only when the standard of comparison is two large numbers specially chosen to have many many prime factors?  Why is that surprising or interesting?

Comment: To summarise, if two coprime integers are rich in factors, their difference tends to be lacking in factors.

Comment: @Assaultous2 You haven't presented any evidence of this. The one example worked out in the comments is just as factor-rich as a random integer of the same size, so by that standard, the statement boils down to "most integers tend to be lacking in factors".